# Conditional field and formsets

Tags: django

**Update:** The uploads are required on the answers that have an upload associated with them.

Say I have a 'question' model like so:

```
Question(Model):
    question = TextField()
    upload = BooleanField()
```

an 'answer' model like so:

```
Answer(Model):
    question = ForeignKey(Question)
    answer = SmallIntegerField()
    upload = FileField()
```

And a form like so:

```
AnswerForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        if (self.instance.question.upload):
            self.Meta.fields = ('answer', 'upload')
            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                InlineRadios('answer'),
                'upload'
            )
        else:
            self.Meta.fields = ('answer',)
            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                InlineRadios('answer'),
            )

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('answer', 'upload')
```

I have a modelformset with these answers displayed fine. Each of these inputs are contained within one larger form, rather than each of these being several separate forms, which is then submitted using one submit button.

Not every answer has an upload field, depending on which question it's answering, hence the conditional field.

**The problem is** that, with this above setup, the only forms that validate are the ones with a displayed upload field, which has an upload input (only answers with an upload will display the filefield). What I'm expecting is happening here is that the formset is expecting each form to have an upload, even though there's not a filefield displayed by every form, and is therefore invalidating every form that doesn't display a filefield, therefore not allowing them to be committed to the database.

What I want, overall, is a formset with forms that have a conditional field, depending on whether or not they have an upload associated with them. Each of the methods that I've attempted, have the same issue as this one.

Is there any way of doing what I'm attempting here?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

null=True and blank=True in the model make the field not required.  required=False in the modelfield will make the form valid even if nothing is put into it.  You can add a clean_field def to the form to customize the conditional field.

Comment: Cheers for the answer. I failed to mention that the uploads are required on the answers with uploads. This would work for the answers without uploads, but would allow the answers with uploads to be validated when they shouldn't be.

Also, could you elaborate on your second point?

Cheers.

Comment: You can overload the dehydration process.  clean[fieldname](self) or clean(self) can get you where you are going.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. I've ended up setting null=True and blank=True for the upload field, but I've overridden clean_upload() and checked the instance for the inclusion of an upload and then raised a validation error if there is no cleaned data for that form.

It's not the most elegant, but it works for now.

Cheers.